# Weird behaviour with only one device and NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents, nsformatter

After weeks of work, I finally released my application yesterday :-)
20 iphones have downloaded my app, and only one is having a problem. I have absolutely no way to debug it because I cannot have access to the device which has the problem.

First of all, I get the json (which is decoded well, even on THE device), then I extract a date:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[myData objectForKey:@"date"]];
```

I want to know when this date was, so I use this function:

```
[DateManager getDateFromNow:date];
```

Which leads to this code:

```
+ (NSString *) getDateFromNow: (NSDate*) aDate{
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    // Get the system calendar
    NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:aDate  toDate:now  options:0];

    int second =[conversionInfo second];
    int minute =[conversionInfo minute];
    int hour =[conversionInfo hour];
    int day =[conversionInfo day];

    if(day != 0){
        if(day == 1){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 day ago"];
        }else{
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i days ago", day];
        }
    }else if(hour != 0){
        if(hour == 1){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 hour ago"];
        }else{
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i hours ago", hour];
        }
    }else if(minute !=0){
        if(minute == 1){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 minute ago"];
        }else{
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i minutes ago", minute];
        }
    }else{
        if(second == 1){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 second ago"];
        }else{
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i seconds ago", second];
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is, that for only one device, the date is calculated as '4932 days ago', and for all other devices it's working well.
Here is the date: `date: "2014-07-04 13:38:01"`

Do you have any clue on what could be wrong?

Many thanks in advance...

edit : 4932 days ago was the first january of 2001. The apple reference date.

Comment: So you get a date, via JSON, from a server but use the current system time zone to decode it?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: In `getDateFromNow:`, what logs `aDate`, `now` and `conversionInfo`?

Comment: I don't have access to the logs :(
Thanks for your help @trojanfoe, but are you sure this is the cause of this problem?

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all (in fact I'm sure it's not), however I would have expected the server to provide times in UTC so that the dates are accurate regardless of where the device is located.

Comment: @Vico i think there is problem with Calendar. if user change his calendar from settings then you can not get proper info. check it out. you should use Gregorian Calendar and then get days.

Comment: try code for convert string to date.`NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
formatter.calendar = sysCalendar;`

Comment: it may helps: **Gregorian** calendar: `-9 days ago`; **Japanese** calendar: `-726111 days ago`; **Buddhist** calendar: `198308 days ago`.

Comment: You are right, there is a problem with my calendar. But when I switch to buddhist one or to Japanese one on my own device, I don't get "4932 days ago". I know for sure that the date of the device is correct for the user.
I've called the user (a friend of mine) and she has this date on her device:  Fri Jul 04 2014 (not in my application)
So I presume it's not only a problem with the calendar.
Thanks for your help !

@holex your result with Gregorian calendar is quite surprising

Comment: You may want to use a system like TestFlight to get access to your friend's logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `systemTimeZone` or `NSCalendar`.

When you are doing date-string conversion you should set NSCalendar.

```
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
// set your NSDateFormatter with calendar.
formatter.calendar = sysCalendar;
```

It will help and one more thing is you should always set **UTC date** or **timestamp** from server end.

Thanks. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: I will push her your solution, and keep you in touch.

Thanks!